# Dataframe after reindex does not show all items in multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

Main goal - to reindex DataFrame with new multiindex that contains new values

```
In[34]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [1,4,2],[2,3,4], [2,2,1]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
In[35]: df = df.set_index(['a', 'b'])
In[36]: df.index
Out[36]:
MultiIndex(levels=[[1, 2], [2, 3, 4]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 1, 0]],
           names=[u'a', u'b'])

In[37]: df_ri = df.reindex_axis([1,2,3,4], level='b', axis=0)
In[39]: df_ri
Out[39]: 
     c
a b   
1 2  3
  4  2
2 3  4
  2  1
In[40]: df_ri.index
Out[40]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4]], #all new values are stored here but are not visible in df
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 3, 2, 1]],
           names=[u'a', u'b'])
```

At the end - df output is not changed. When I Look at new index - it has new values, but they are not shown. I can avoid that by creating new df with that new index and then merging old df with new one - but it is not the best approach. Any suggestions?

Comment: This type of multi-index reindexing has been broken (for a while), it doesn't reorder properly, will try to get to in 0.15.1: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4088

Comment: @Jeff thanks, any suggestions how to avoid it?